# (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) Error with gui

Tags: java

I am making a simple gui program in java. When i click run it gives me an error that looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(Unknown Source)
at main.cool(main.java:31)
at main$1.run(main.java:43)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

protected JButton click, fun;

public main()
{
    click = new JButton("Click");
    click.setActionCommand("click");
    click.addActionListener(this);
    add(click);
    click.setSize(16, 16);
    fun = new JButton("wow");
    fun.setActionCommand("wow");
    fun.addActionListener(this);
    add(fun);

}

public static void cool()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main main = new main();
    frame.setContentPane(main);
    frame.setSize(128, 128);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
        public void run()
        {
            cool();
        }
    });

}





public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if("click".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    {
        System.out.println("oh right");
    } else if ("wow".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

}
```

I believe the bug may be in the cool() method; with the setContentPane line. but not sure. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Maybe you mean to `extend JPanel` not `extend JFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; the bug is triggered in the `frame.setContentPanel()` in your `cool()` method in your `main` class. Your `main` class should `extend JPanel` instead of `extend JFrame`.

**Aside**: avoid declaring local variables which match class names; and, avoid declaring class names which are the same as standard method names...so, rename your `main` class as `Main` (if you must, but try to be more descriptive...perhaps `Application`), and make your local variable name something other than `main`...perhaps `m` or `application`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `main` extends `JFrame` instead of `JPanel`, so you are calling `frame.setContentPane()` on another `JFrame`, and it doesn't make sense to have a `JFrame` inside a `JFrame`. Change the superclass to `JPanel` and the error will go away